# "Unable to open database file" using SQLite on Windows Phone 7

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

I am using SQLite for Windows Phone 7 (http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/) and I have done every steps from this tutorial (http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx)

Then I try to make some simple application with basic features like select and delete. App is working properly till I want to make one of this operations. After I click select or delete, compiler shows me errors that he is unable to open database file...

I have no idea why?

Comment: what do you mean, by the compiler shows you errors? You mean the program instead?

Comment: I am beginner in WP7 so I added a screen of this. [link]https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/g09-xLru6B0WVF3QcWPgiQ?feat=directlink[/link] It appears after I try to use button with delete function

Comment: check if the db file exists as i explain in the post. if that doesnt help, i would fill up the database in the application by inserting data (instead of using an external program)

Comment: ok, can you just explain me where use this code? to fill db I use SQLite Manager in firefox so and db is in project folder so it exist..

Comment: i would recommend you to start with a smaller and easier project... Just run the shown code somewhere before that error happens and check the content of the `exists` variable. it has to be true.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same Sqlite client, and had the same problem. This problem occurs because the sqlite try to create file in IsolatedFileStorage "DatabaseName.sqlite-journal" and it does not have enough permissions for that. I solved the problem, so that created "DatabaseName.sqlite-journal" before copying database to IsolatedFileStorage. Here's my method that did it:

```
private void CopyFromContentToStorage(String assemblyName, String dbName)
{
IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        string uri = dbName + "-journal";

        store.CreateFile(uri);

        using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/" + assemblyName + ";component/" + dbName,UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream dest = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(dbName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, store);
            input.Position = 0;
            CopyStream(input, dest);
            dest.Flush();
            dest.Close();
            dest.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

it helped me, and worked well.

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file exists?
You can check like that:

```
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            exists = store.FileExists(DbfileName);
        }
```